# Create a Folder then Save as many .txt Documents as I want

Tags: python, file, directory, path, save

```
    import os
    path = os.getcwd()
    print(path)
    y = False
    while y == False:
        dirName = input("Folder name: ")
        try:
            # Create target Directory
            os.mkdir(dirName)
            print("Directory '" , dirName ,  "' Created ")
            y = True
        except FileExistsError:
            print("Directory " , dirName ,  " already exists")
            
    folderDir = os.path.join(path, dirName)
    
    y = int(input("Number of profs: "))
    for a in range(y):
        with open("number.txt","r") as z:
            num = z.read()
            num = int(num)
            newNum = (int(num)+1)
            numProf = ("profile"+str(newNum))
            with open("number.txt","w") as file:
                file.write(str(newNum))
                file.close()
                with open(folderDir+numProf+".txt","x") as f:
                    print(numProf)

###THIS DELETES THE FILES
    ##RESET FILE NUMBER
    reset = input(str("Delete all files (Y/N)?"))
    if reset == "y" or reset == "Y":
        delete = True
    
    if reset == "n" or reset == "N":
        delete = False
    
    if delete == True:
        with open("number.txt","w") as file:
            file.write("0")
            file.close()
        notRemoved = 0
        removed = 0
        for x in range(0,101):
            try:
                os.remove("profile"+str(x)+".txt")
                removed += 1
            except:
                notRemoved +=1
        print("Deleted "+str(removed))
```

This is the code^
Number is there to keep track of how many files there are.
Not sure how I can open number to check how many there are as the directory the  changes and saves in the same file as number.txt whilst still creating a new empty folder.

Comment: nothing to do with your question, but perhaps nice to know:

Instead of `if reset == "y" or reset == "Y":` you could better write `if reset.lower() == "y":`

But in your current case your code would fail if you ever type a letter different to "Y", "y", "N", "n" (just try it out)

To avoid this you could immediately write:
`delete = reset.lower() == "y"` which would mean, `delete == True` if reset is "y" (or "Y") and false otherwise.

And in order to perform the check just write: `if delete:` (`delete == True` works as well but is unpythonic /  not used that often in the python world)

Comment: also: `reset = input(str("Delete all files (Y/N)?"))` is the same as `reset = input("Delete all files (Y/N)?")` also. normally it's good practice to keep files only open as short as possible and to close them as soon as possible.

This  means, that for `with open("number.txt","r") as z:`
you should only keep the next line (`num = z.read()`) indented and you can unindent all the other lines following it by 4 (until the `###THIS DELE...` comment)

Same for `with open("number.txt","w") as file:`
Just keep the line following it indented, get rid of `flle.close()` and unident the others.

Comment: You also don't need the `file.close()` in the other `with` statement. The file will be closed automatically as soon as you leave he `with` statement.

Happy coding with python!!

Answer (score 1):

```
folderDir = os.path.join(path, dirName,numProf)
with open(folderDir+".txt","x") as f:
    print(folderDir+numProf)
```

changed that code and it worked